# Get label.text from UILabel in an instance method iOS 7

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uilabel

I have a pickerview that displays an array of locations (2 components); below that are 2 UILabels (2 under each component).

When a user opens the app, the picker defaults to the first object in each array in the picker components and changes the label below to reflect that selection.

So it would look something like this:

```
|PickerComponent1|PickerComponent2|

|     Label 1    |     Label 2    |
```

It displays the labels correctly when [viewDidLoad] is called.  The labels changed to the appropriate names.

I created an instance method - but I can't pass the text value of the labels to that method.

The log displays (null) and it's coming back as empty.
Any ideas on how I can pass that label text to the method appropriately?

*edit: if I put that code that assigned label1 and the NSLog line into the viewDidLoad method it prints out the label text appropriately.  When I put it into the method it does not.

My viewDidLoad in my .m file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    //set self as delegate for tripPicker
    _tripPicker.delegate = self;

    //Set size of tripPicker & datePicker
    _tripPicker.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.60, 0.60);
    _datePicker.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.60, 0.60);

    //Call method to get array of school names (reusable)
    MetaMiles *model = [MetaMiles schoolNameList];
    _schoolArray1 = (NSArray *)model;
    _schoolArray2 = (NSArray *)model;

    //Set date to current date
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
    _dateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Date of trip: %@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.datePicker.date ]];

    //Set selector method for datePicker so on the value change it updates the date
    [self.datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(updateLabelForDate:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    [super viewDidLoad];


    //Set labels to be appropriate schools
    begSchoolLabel.text = [_schoolArray1 objectAtIndex:[_tripPicker selectedRowInComponent:0]];
    endSchoolLabel.text = [_schoolArray2 objectAtIndex:[_tripPicker selectedRowInComponent:1]];


    //Update the Mileage indicator to display miles between currently selected values
    ML54AddMilesViewController *milesObject = [[ML54AddMilesViewController alloc]init];
    NSArray *currentMiles = [milesObject getMileage];
    NSLog(@"Current Miles first run: %@",currentMiles);


}
```

My getMileage method:

```
- (NSArray *)getMileage {
    //Update the Mileage indicator to display miles between currently selected values
    NSString *begSchool = begSchoolLabel.text;
    NSLog(@"FIRE THIS OFF : %@",begSchool);
    NSString *endSchool = endSchoolLabel.text;
    NSPredicate *milesFilter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"beg_school=%@ AND end_school=%@", begSchool, endSchool];
    NSArray *resultMiles = [MetaMiles MR_findAllWithPredicate:milesFilter];
    if (!resultMiles || ![resultMiles count]) {
        NSLog(@"Empty Array");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Our array is: %@", [resultMiles objectAtIndex:0]);}
    return resultMiles;
}
```

Comment: That shouldn't even compile. Is this your exact code?

Comment: No, it's just the main part I'm trying to get to Log the value of the label.   But the Log just displays Null

Comment: It will only display null if the label's text property is null, or if the label itself is null. Are you sure you aren't trying to access this property at some point before the label is created/ text value set?

Comment: I set the text with the item from the picker in the viewDidLoad method - and that displays without issue.  If I put that code to assign the label1 variable and the line to log the label.text into the viewDidLoad method it also displays appropriately in the Log.  It's only when I move it to the method that it stops displaying and shows me 'null' instead.

Comment: You're going to need to show more code for a diagnosis.

Comment: added more information - my viewDidLoad and my method.  Everything is appropriate in my .h file.  It's something going on in my .m

Comment: "The log displays (null) and it's coming back as empty" -- what log returns null, and what is coming back empty?

Comment: The log, displays (null).  See the code, where I wrote NSLog (...); that - causes the log to display (null) for the variable in the code.

If I put that same code in the viewDidLoad method - it works fine.  But in my method I created it just spits out (null)

Comment: I see 4 NSLogs in your posted code. Which one are you talking about?

Comment: NSLog(@"FIRE THIS OFF : %@",begSchool);

That's the one.  Just trying to get it to repeat the name of the school

Comment: How are the labels being created? Are they in a XIB? you appear to be using `_tripPicker` for the picker, but not `_begSchoolLabel` for the labels (no underscore), doesn't using the _ variable mean you are bypassing the setter? Or have you defined them yourself?

Comment: property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *begSchoolLabel;


    property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *endSchoolLabel;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was instead of using the label to get the text - I just had it nab whatever the picker had chosen.  The label updates appropriately but for some reason I couldn't pass it between methods - this other way I was able to do that.